# Facebook login button won't fire data-onlogin

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am building this new site trying to use Facebook as login authentication. But I also need user profile to get his data in databank, also I need to know that he is in. I used the "button builder" of Facebook Developers site. The result is strange, there is no callback... So I add one by the rules of the documentation:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-width="" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-layout="default" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="true" data-onlogin="(evt)=>{ console.log('Facebook Login'); loginFacebook(evt); }"></div>
```

I can login and logout through this button but the function won't fire, nothing appears in the console but the message:

```
Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'worker-src'.
```

I am using Safari 14.1.1 and I log in websites normally using Facebook login button, but can't make it work in my own website... sad... :-(

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is arrow function syntax supposed to work in this place, I wonder ... Have you tried just specifying the name of a function in that place?

Comment: Maybe. As I was in a hurry, I did my own button and used FB.login() to make it work. Also I have seen many websites using their own buttons instead of this solution. I might try to put only the function name, but it's strange, in the docs it is mentioned a function object.